# show the total count value at beginning

Tags: php

I have no experience in php but i am facing a problem in php.

i have a php code like this:

```
<div>   
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" 
                id="selectAll" class="checkbox"> Select All </li>

        <?php
            $count = 0;
            foreach ($caseList as $testcase)
            {
        ?>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="testcases" 
                       class="checkbox" 
                       value="<?php echo $testcase->id; ?>">
                <?php echo $testcase->name; ?>
                <?php $count++;?>
            </li>
        <?php
            }
        ?>

        <li> <?php echo "Total Test Case COunt: $count";?> </li>
    </ul>
```

But i want to print "Total Test Case count" at beginning list. How i can do this?

Comment: Advice. Don't mix php and html like that.

Comment: @frosty i know it might be bad to do so due to code clarity, is there any other downside to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a [`count($caseList)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) at the top.

```
<div>   
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" id="selectAll" class="checkbox"> Select All </li>

        <li> <?php echo "Total Test Case COunt: " . count($caseList);?> </li>

        <?php
            $count = 0;
            foreach ($caseList as $testcase)
            {
        ?>

            <li><input type="checkbox" name="testcases" class="checkbox" value="<?php echo $testcase->id; ?>"><?php echo $testcase->name; ?><?php $count++;?></li>
        <?php
            }
        ?>



    </ul>
```

Comment: thanks all, i think my question was annoying to u all as it was too simple

Comment: Honestly, I don't think it's the fact it was too simple, I think it was because this is a basic thing that could quite easily be found with a Google of "PHP count array". Still, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the length of the array without a counter using the `count` function.

```
$count = count($caseList);
```

So your final code could be like

```
div>   
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" id="selectAll" class="checkbox"> Select All </li>

    <?php
        $total = count($caseList);
        echo "Total Test Case Count: $total"
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($caseList as $testcase)
        {
    ?>

        <li><input type="checkbox" name="testcases" class="checkbox" value="<?php echo $testcase->id; ?>"><?php echo $testcase->name; ?><?php $count++;?></li>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to move increment from "li" tag

```
<div>   
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" 
            id="selectAll" class="checkbox"> Select All </li>

    <?php
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($caseList as $testcase)
        {
    ?>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="testcases" 
                   class="checkbox" 
                   value="<?php echo $testcase->id; ?>">
            <?php echo $testcase->name; ?>
        </li>
    <?php
          $count++;
        }
    ?>

    <li> <?php echo "Total Test Case COunt: $count";?> </li>
</ul>
```